# Make A UIScrollView scroll like a UIPageController

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way that i can make a UIScrollView scroll like a UIPageController or like a page because currently when we scroll UIScrollView its like free..

Comment: Yes, the scrollview supports paging, please check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, UIScrollView has the functionality you are looking for. Look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html)

Comment: Link-only answers become meaningless in the event that the link breaks. At least include an outline of the solution in tje text; ideally code.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas, you're 100% right I will take it into account. I faced myself this situation with broken links several times. I did upvote the answer of @Pyro

Answer (score 2):

As Heximal as mentioned scrollview has property `pagingEnabled` which you need to enable to make pagination in scrollview

Your sample code can be like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollPagination: UIScrollView!
var numberOfPages:CGFloat = 5

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollPagination.pagingEnabled = true
    scrollPagination.contentSize = CGSizeMake(numberOfPages * scrollPagination.frame.size.width, scrollPagination.frame.size.height)

    for i in 0...Int(numberOfPages) {
        let tmpLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(CGFloat(i) * self.view.bounds.width + 20, 20, 120, 20))
        tmpLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        tmpLabel.text = "This is page \(i)"
        scrollPagination.addSubview(tmpLabel)
    }
}
```

Another code reference for your code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29300300/4557505