# Is it possible to create a scroll view with an animated page control in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

The designer wants the following animation from a swipe gesture.

[image: Reference image from: https://ios.uplabs.com/posts/cards-swipe-concept-animation]

As it can be seen the user can swipe cards and see what each card has. At the same time, the user can see in the right side of the screen the following card and the last one in the left. Also, cards are changing their size while the user is moving the scroll.

I have already worked with page control views but I have no idea if this is possible with a page Control (which actually is the question of this post).

Also, I have already tried with a collectionView but when I swipe (actually is an horizontal scroll) the scroll has an uncomfortable inertia and also, I have no idea how to make the animation.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074454/how-to-create-a-scroll-view-with-a-page-control-using-swift) a scrolled page control is implemented but now I just wondering if and animation like the gif provided is possible.

If the answer is yes, I would really appreciate if you can give tips of how I can make this possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try UICollectionViewLayout and UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes to make pages https://www.raywenderlich.com/107687/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-spinning-wheel. For transactions I'll advise UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

Comment: Look for a Carousel library :)
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=carousel

Answer (score 10):

Based on the Denislava Shentova comment I found a good library that solves this issue.

For all people in the future and their work hours, I just took code from [UPCarouselFlowLayout library](https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout) and deleted some I didn't need.

Here is the code of a simple viewController that shows the following result: 
[image]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    // CollectionView variable:
    var collectionView : UICollectionView?

    // Variables asociated to collection view:
    fileprivate var currentPage: Int = 0
    fileprivate var pageSize: CGSize {
        let layout = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UPCarouselFlowLayout
        var pageSize = layout.itemSize
        pageSize.width += layout.minimumLineSpacing
        return pageSize
    }

    fileprivate var colors: [UIColor] = [UIColor.black, UIColor.red, UIColor.green, UIColor.yellow]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.addCollectionView()
        self.setupLayout()

    }

    func setupLayout(){
        // This is just an utility custom class to calculate screen points
        // to the screen based in a reference view. You can ignore this and write the points manually where is required.
        let pointEstimator = RelativeLayoutUtilityClass(referenceFrameSize: self.view.frame.size)

        self.collectionView?.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collectionView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: pointEstimator.relativeHeight(multiplier: 0.1754)).isActive = true
        self.collectionView?.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        self.collectionView?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: pointEstimator.relativeHeight(multiplier: 0.6887)).isActive = true

        self.currentPage = 0
    }


    func addCollectionView(){

        // This is just an utility custom class to calculate screen points
        // to the screen based in a reference view. You can ignore this and write the points manually where is required.
        let pointEstimator = RelativeLayoutUtilityClass(referenceFrameSize: self.view.frame.size)

        // This is where the magic is done. With the flow layout the views are set to make costum movements. See https://github.com/ink-spot/UPCarouselFlowLayout for more info
        let layout = UPCarouselFlowLayout()
        // This is used for setting the cell size (size of each view in this case)
        // Here I'm writting 400 points of height and the 73.33% of the height view frame in points.
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: pointEstimator.relativeWidth(multiplier: 0.73333), height: 400)
        // Setting the scroll direction
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        // Collection view initialization, the collectionView must be
        // initialized with a layout object.
        self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        // This line if for able programmatic constrains.
        self.collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // CollectionView delegates and dataSource:
        self.collectionView?.delegate = self
        self.collectionView?.dataSource = self
        // Registering the class for the collection view cells
        self.collectionView?.register(CardCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")

        // Spacing between cells:
        let spacingLayout = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UPCarouselFlowLayout
        spacingLayout.spacingMode = UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode.overlap(visibleOffset: 20)

        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView!)

    }

    // MARK: - Card Collection Delegate & DataSource

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return colors.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! CardCell

        cell.customView.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UIScrollViewDelegate

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let layout = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UPCarouselFlowLayout
        let pageSide = (layout.scrollDirection == .horizontal) ? self.pageSize.width : self.pageSize.height
        let offset = (layout.scrollDirection == .horizontal) ? scrollView.contentOffset.x : scrollView.contentOffset.y
        currentPage = Int(floor((offset - pageSide / 2) / pageSide) + 1)
    }

}

class CardCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let customView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        return view
    }()


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.addSubview(self.customView)

        self.customView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        self.customView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        self.customView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        self.customView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true


    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


} // End of CardCell


class RelativeLayoutUtilityClass {

    var heightFrame: CGFloat?
    var widthFrame: CGFloat?

    init(referenceFrameSize: CGSize){
        heightFrame = referenceFrameSize.height
        widthFrame = referenceFrameSize.width
    }

    func relativeHeight(multiplier: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{

        return multiplier * self.heightFrame!
    }

    func relativeWidth(multiplier: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return multiplier * self.widthFrame!

    }



}
```

Note that there are some other clases in this code but temporarily you can run the whole code in the ViewController.swift file. After you test, please split them into different files.

In order tu run this code, you need the following module. Make a file called UPCarouselFlowLayout.swift and paste all this code:

```
import UIKit


public enum UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode {
    case fixed(spacing: CGFloat)
    case overlap(visibleOffset: CGFloat)
}


open class UPCarouselFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    fileprivate struct LayoutState {
        var size: CGSize
        var direction: UICollectionViewScrollDirection
        func isEqual(_ otherState: LayoutState) -> Bool {
            return self.size.equalTo(otherState.size) && self.direction == otherState.direction
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable open var sideItemScale: CGFloat = 0.6
    @IBInspectable open var sideItemAlpha: CGFloat = 0.6
    open var spacingMode = UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode.fixed(spacing: 40)

    fileprivate var state = LayoutState(size: CGSize.zero, direction: .horizontal)


    override open func prepare() {
        super.prepare()

        let currentState = LayoutState(size: self.collectionView!.bounds.size, direction: self.scrollDirection)

        if !self.state.isEqual(currentState) {
            self.setupCollectionView()
            self.updateLayout()
            self.state = currentState
        }
    }

    fileprivate func setupCollectionView() {
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return }
        if collectionView.decelerationRate != UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast {
            collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
        }
    }

    fileprivate func updateLayout() {
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return }

        let collectionSize = collectionView.bounds.size
        let isHorizontal = (self.scrollDirection == .horizontal)

        let yInset = (collectionSize.height - self.itemSize.height) / 2
        let xInset = (collectionSize.width - self.itemSize.width) / 2
        self.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(yInset, xInset, yInset, xInset)

        let side = isHorizontal ? self.itemSize.width : self.itemSize.height
        let scaledItemOffset =  (side - side*self.sideItemScale) / 2
        switch self.spacingMode {
        case .fixed(let spacing):
            self.minimumLineSpacing = spacing - scaledItemOffset
        case .overlap(let visibleOffset):
            let fullSizeSideItemOverlap = visibleOffset + scaledItemOffset
            let inset = isHorizontal ? xInset : yInset
            self.minimumLineSpacing = inset - fullSizeSideItemOverlap
        }
    }

    override open func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override open func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let superAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect),
            let attributes = NSArray(array: superAttributes, copyItems: true) as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]
            else { return nil }
        return attributes.map({ self.transformLayoutAttributes($0) })
    }

    fileprivate func transformLayoutAttributes(_ attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView else { return attributes }
        let isHorizontal = (self.scrollDirection == .horizontal)

        let collectionCenter = isHorizontal ? collectionView.frame.size.width/2 : collectionView.frame.size.height/2
        let offset = isHorizontal ? collectionView.contentOffset.x : collectionView.contentOffset.y
        let normalizedCenter = (isHorizontal ? attributes.center.x : attributes.center.y) - offset

        let maxDistance = (isHorizontal ? self.itemSize.width : self.itemSize.height) + self.minimumLineSpacing
        let distance = min(abs(collectionCenter - normalizedCenter), maxDistance)
        let ratio = (maxDistance - distance)/maxDistance

        let alpha = ratio * (1 - self.sideItemAlpha) + self.sideItemAlpha
        let scale = ratio * (1 - self.sideItemScale) + self.sideItemScale
        attributes.alpha = alpha
        attributes.transform3D = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, scale, scale, 1)
        attributes.zIndex = Int(alpha * 10)

        return attributes
    }

    override open func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView , !collectionView.isPagingEnabled,
            let layoutAttributes = self.layoutAttributesForElements(in: collectionView.bounds)
            else { return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset) }

        let isHorizontal = (self.scrollDirection == .horizontal)

        let midSide = (isHorizontal ? collectionView.bounds.size.width : collectionView.bounds.size.height) / 2
        let proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin = (isHorizontal ? proposedContentOffset.x : proposedContentOffset.y) + midSide

        var targetContentOffset: CGPoint
        if isHorizontal {
            let closest = layoutAttributes.sorted { abs($0.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) < abs($1.center.x - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) }.first ?? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()
            targetContentOffset = CGPoint(x: floor(closest.center.x - midSide), y: proposedContentOffset.y)
        }
        else {
            let closest = layoutAttributes.sorted { abs($0.center.y - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) < abs($1.center.y - proposedContentOffsetCenterOrigin) }.first ?? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes()
            targetContentOffset = CGPoint(x: proposedContentOffset.x, y: floor(closest.center.y - midSide))
        }

        return targetContentOffset
    }
}
```

Again, this module was made by Paul Ulric, you can installed with cocoa.

Comment: great job creating this basic example Hugo!