# swiping between images within the same view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I'm new to swift but have android experience.  Is there a iOS control similar to the android viewpager?  I'm creating an app that has a view controller that contains a large image view and several text fields.  The image view covers half the screen or more and the text fields take up the rest of the screen. I need to swipe between images while the text stays in place. What's the best way to implement this? I thought of adding swipe gesture recognizer and changing the image on swipe but is that the best way?

Comment: The best way is to use UIScrollView with paging enabled.

Comment: You can use UIScrollView and UIPageControl for that. Check [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074454/how-to-create-a-scroll-view-with-a-page-control-using-swift) out.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/159481/uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: "Is there a iOS control similar to the android viewpager?" UIPageViewController maybe???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIPageControl. It has capability to swipe between pages(ie page with image and text)

Comment: It would be more helpful if you also post examples in addition to identifying the recommended class.

Comment: I ended up adding a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl to the View Controller.  Worked Great!  Thanks to @Phyber for the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Pageview controller, if you're using a storyboard.

1. Drag a pageviewcontroller into your storyboard
2. On your main view controller, drag a container view and **CTRL + DRAG** from your container view towards your pageviewcontroller and choose **Embed**
3. Now on your pageviewController define your controllers, for each image make one viewcontroller. So for example if you have 3 images, make 3 viewcontrollers for each. this is the simplest you can do.
4. Other option would be using CollectionView