# collectionview of images & click on cell show image on popup which can be scroll to see other images also

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have images in `collectionview`. When I click on `cell` i need to show image on popup which can be scroll to see other images also in swift 3. i have given link for my `collectionview` screen shot.

[My Collectionview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9wFs.png)

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far, at least the part(s) relevant to your question.

Comment: what kind of pop up? a full screen or just a custom-sized pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIScrollView` to achieve this functionality. when your select cell, load all images into `scrollView` with `isPagingEnabled` and show your images. 
For `Page View controller` checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074454/how-to-create-a-scroll-view-with-a-page-control-using-swift)

Comment: Thnx A ton this is what i am looking for!!

Comment: don't post other answer as yours so instead of posting other's answer link try to suggest link as comment.