# Embed UIViewController inside static UITableViewController cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a static UITableViewController with 5 sections.

In first section I embed UIPageViewController into UITableViewCell.
But my app become freeze and no error appear.

I try to remove UIPageViewController and it works.

Can I have UIPageViewController inside UITableViewCell?

Or did I miss something?

Comment: Why do you use UITableViewController? My idea would be to look into UICollectionViewController whether it fits your needs. Another idea would be to use UIScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The app become freeze caused by Realm.

We can embed UIViewControlle in UITableViewCell, but UITableViewController must be static Cells (Settings in your storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

You can not add UIPageViewController into UITableViewCell. Try to add UIScrollview in UITableView cell content view. Decrease priority of width of Scrollview. Then add  page control in Scrollview to check current page as per scrollview swipe. Hope Below link will help.

[Page Control in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795722/how-do-i-implement-uipagecontrol-in-swift)